# JSON in python from mysql with additional key value pairs

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

This is the code used to fetch data from DB

```
import pymysql

import json



     conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='test', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")

    rows = []
    for row in cursor:
        rows += [row]

    print(json.dumps(rows, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Output  in json is -

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "id": 50
    },
    {
        "name": "Mark",
        "id": 57
    }
]
```

But I want the output in this format -

```
{
    "version": "5.2",
    "user_type": "online",
    "user":
    [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "id": 50
        },
        {
            "name": "Mark",
            "id": 57
        }
    ]
}
```

where the version and user_type can be manually entered or appended to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap the result set in a dict of your liking then.

```
# ...

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
response = {
    "version": "5.2",
    "user_type": "online",
    "user": list(cursor),  # This is equivalent to iterating over the cursor yourself.
}
print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))

# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict with the version, the user type, and the user (where for the key 'user' you enter rows as the value).  Then convert that to json using `json.dump` or `json.dumps`:

```
data = { "version": "5.2",  "user_type": "online",  "user":rows }

print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```